# Can we have a well founded set that is not an element of the cumulative hierarchy, in this fragment of ZF?

Tags: set-theory

Is it consistent with $``\sf Z + foundation  \ schema + \forall  \alpha \exists V_\alpha + \forall x \exists t=\text{tcl}(x)"$ to have a ***set*** that doesn't belong to any stage of the cumulative hierarchy? Provided that the infinity axiom is phrased in terms of von Neumann ordinals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider Mathias' $\cal M_\lambda$. For a limit ordinal $\lambda>\omega$, $\cal M_\lambda$ is the class of all sets $x$ such that $\sup\operatorname{tcl}(x)\cap\lambda<\lambda$.

It is not hard to verify that:

1. This is a proper class.
2. It is a model of $\sf Z$ (with Foundation, actually).
3. Its ordinals, as seen as von Neumann ordinals are exactly $\lambda$.
4. $V_\lambda\subseteq\cal M_\lambda$.

So in a very deep sense, most sets do not belong to the von Neumann hierarchy. And if you want to have "additional properties", just choose your $\lambda$ carefully. So you can have, for example, that the von Neumann universe is a model of $\sf ZFC$ if you assume that $V_\lambda$ was one.

Comment: What's the proof that $V_\lambda \subsetneq \mathcal M_\lambda$? Since its that what is wanted

Comment: Take any set $x$ in $V_\lambda$ which is not an ordinal, say $x=V_\omega$, and start iterating $x_0=x$; $x_{\alpha+1}=x_\alpha\cup\{x_\alpha\}$; and $x_\alpha=\bigcup x_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ for limit ordinals. Easily, $x_\lambda\notin V_\lambda$ (or, if you want, continue up to $|V_\lambda|^+$.

Comment: But $\sf sup \text{ tcl}(x_\lambda)$ can be equal to $\lambda$, so, it won't be an element of $\mathcal M_\lambda$.

Comment: Let's say we started with $V_\omega$, for concreteness. At what point do we add $\omega$ to the set?

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks.